Jupyter lab- Trying to load TUDataset-Proteins // LocalFileSystem.mv() error
I am trying to load the PROTEINS dataset from TUDataset using the following commands (I am working in Jupyter lab).
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset
dataset = TUDataset(root='.', name='PROTEINS')

I get the following error:
LocalFileSystem.mv() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

This is the only database from torch_geometric that is giving me problems loading, I have tried Planetoid, MoleculeNet and several others and they all work at the first try. Sorry if the question is very basic but I am new to python and can't find the exact error poster here.
Tried to load it in VS-studio just in case it was a problem with Jupyter lab but the same problem arose.

The affected package, fsspec, recently made a breaking change in this regard. I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading it to version 2024.3.1.

Worked perfectly, just please add the command.
pip install fsspec==2024.3.1 

I had the same error but was able to fix it by creating a new conda/virtual environment.
I am not sure what exactly the problem was but I suspect some module dependencies/conflicts. After creating a new environment I installed the required modules with pip.
As you mentioned that you're new to python, I recommend getting familiar with virtual environments.
Create new environment and activate it in a terminal:
conda create -n my-env
conda activate my-env

Install new modules in that environment:
conda install pip
pip install torch
pip install torch_geometric
pip install -q torch-scatter~=2.1.0 torch-sparse~=0.6.16 torch-cluster~=1.6.0 torch-spline-conv~=1.2.1 torch-geometric==2.2.0 -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html

